# Firebase error writing to Firestore via a Function: "7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions"

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a simple Firebase Function that adds a record to Firestore with TypeScript. The cut down version of the code is:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const config = functions.config();

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.database.enableLogging(true);

exports.subscriptions = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const requestSubscription = req.body;
      const subscription = {
        subscription_id: requestSubscription.subscription_id,
        email: requestSubscription.email || ""
      };

      const id = subscription.subscription_id;
      const dbSubscriptions = admin.firestore().collection("subscriptions");
      await dbSubscriptions.doc(id).set(subscription);

      return res.status(200).send(`Success`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.stack);
      return res.status(500).send(`Error`);
    }
  }
);
```

This works as expected locally. When I deploy, I get this error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1214:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:590:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:640:8)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:867:24)
```

My functions/package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The only link I'm getting searching for this error is this unanswered question:
[PERMISSION_DENIED Firestore CloudFunction TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910274/permission-denied-firestore-cloudfunction-typescript)

I've set my Firestore rules to allow anyone to read and write as well even though the above is using admin and it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `functions.config().firebase` is obsolete since version 1.0 of firebase-functions.  You should just init with no arguments now.  Also you should import firebase-functions before firebase-admin.  Don't know if these will fix anything, but please try.  Also update all your npm dependencies and note the versions in your question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the quick reply. I've added my package.json to the question. Using "firebase-admin": "5.12.1", "firebase-functions": "1.0.3". I tried removing the arguments and swapping the imports but there was no difference.

Comment: @DougStevenson: So I'm finding it I use "admin.initializeApp" while supplying the privateKey, databaseURL, clientEmail and projectId it works remotely. I'm really stumped at why the recommended way isn't working. Have I missed some server setup step? I've no idea what to try next.

Comment: Try reporting this to Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Firebase support about this and they didn't know what was going on either. I created a new project, deployed and it worked. Perhaps it's just a weird glitch with new projects.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue while updating my IAM/Service account value and I think I figured it out.

If you use Firebase Admin SDK without providing any credentials in Firebase Functions like this `firebaseAdmin.initializeApp()` then your functions will use default application credentials.

The default credentials uses the following service account `{project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` where `{project-id}` will be your firebase/google cloud project id. This account is often created automatically when you created Firebase project or used few of google cloud services.

Anyhow, `{project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` by default has `Editor` level permission. You can check this out in [Google Cloud - IAM & Admin - IAM] page. I thought it had too much permissions so I basically removed that permission from the service account, and decided to manually add more restrictive permissions. (At that time, I did not know that firebase/cloud functions use this service account.

After making those changes, my functions which access Firestore soon started encountering `Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.` errors. 
In order to solve this issue, I had to do the following 2 things.

- Added back `Editor` level permission back to the default service account.
- Deleted Firestore functions completely using Firebase console, and re-deployed them using `firebase deploy --only functions` command.

After completing above 2 steps, my cloud functions started working correctly as expected.

Comment: In my case I had working functions and after enabling IAM they broke. These steps fixed it!

Comment: I would say the last week of my life I've only had part time attention to devote to the Dread Pirate Roberts, I mean Error 7 Permission Denied. I wasted evil amounts of time with every person talking about firestore rules. God bless the person who emphasized admin.firestore() could care less about firestore security rules. But I digress, my issue was somehow, someway the <projectid>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com was missing Project->Editor role. I don't know how it disappeared. In fact I took the day off my regular job to work on this as it's for a pet project. So deepest gratitude to you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

My project was created in google cloud initially, then connecting that project to firebase.

In my case the issue was `{project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` didn't had `Editor` role, as soon as I added Editor roles for that service account, it started working

p.s
Also for the first time, the user should be `Owner` to be able to create firestore database, otherwise you see this message in firestore page `To manage Cloud Firestore, ask a project owner for the necessary permissions`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `Editor` role to the Cloud Run service account `{project-id}-compute@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` resolved the issue.