# Error 7: Missing or insufficient permissions cloud functions/firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing an app using firebase as a backend, and I am trying to write to the database, but am getting "Error 7:  Missing or insufficient permissions."  Someone told me cloud functions bypasses the firebase permissions, so I'm not sure what could be causing this error.  Can someone please take a look?

Here are my permissions:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var express = require('express');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const app = express();

let db = admin.firestore();

app.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {


  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;


  //creating document.  Here is where it isn't working

  let docRef = db.collection('UsersMain').doc('firstdoc');

    let data = {
    Email: 'a@gmail.com',
    UserName: 'Matt'
  };

  let setDoc = docRef.set(data).then(() =>  {
    res.send('Login Complete');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});

});



const api1 = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = {api1};
```

and here is the error I'm getting:

```
{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>      at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/mg8686./Desktop/mattsapp/mattsappfinal/backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
>      at Http2CallStream.call.on (/Users/mg8686./Desktop/mattsapp/mattsappfinal/backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
>      at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
>      at process.nextTick (/Users/mg8686./Desktop/mattsapp/mattsappfinal/backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:97:22)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>    code: 7,
>    details: 'Missing or insufficient permissions.',
>    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
```

Can someone please take a look?  Thanks!

Comment: not sure if it'll work, try initialising admin as admin.initializeApp(); instead of admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

Comment: Hi @ked, thanks for your help!  I am still getting a Error:   7 PERMISSION_DENIED error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions check this out

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? In the Cloud Functions console? In the browser when you call one of the endpoints you expose through the Cloud Function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firestore: PERMISSION\_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for all your help.  I get the error in the terminal.  I am running the functions locally with firebase serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matias Seguel's solution worked for me listed here: [Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore Trigger produces: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850494/firebase-cloud-functions-firestore-trigger-produces-error-7-permission-denied)

It isn't a great production solution but for development purposes it works.

Comment: Yes! this url looks good...