# Firebase Callable Function Permissions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Angular app has two functions in Firebase. One trigger(document.create), and one callable. The trigger one executes without issue. The callable one is throwing a permission issue
`Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions`

My index.ts

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

const triggerFN = require('./trigger-function');
const callableFN = require('./callable-function');

exports.triggerFN = triggerFN.triggerFN;
exports.callableFN = callableFN.callableFN;
```

My callable function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const callableFN = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      console.log('line 1')

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', 'email@home.com').get()
       .then((qSnap: any) => {
        console.log('line 2');
        // this never gets hit
        return {state: 'ok'}
       })
       .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return {state: 'error', details: error}
       });
       console.log('line 3')  

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return {state: 'error'};
    }
})
```

My trigger function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const triggerFN = functions.firestore.document('invites/{gameId}').onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
    console.log(snap.data())
    try {
         admin.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', 'email@home.com).get()
        .then((qSnap: any) => {

            }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.error(err);
            }) ;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

And my permissions

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Both of these functions work in the emulator.

The function executes, since I can log information. And it can't be the security rules, since the trigger function works without issue. It looks like the context.auth? is not being applied to the callable function.

I've tried [Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore Trigger produces: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850494/firebase-cloud-functions-firestore-trigger-produces-error-7-permission-denied)

I've tried redeploying the functions to different regions. I've tried initializing the admin with a json key.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

[Screen cap of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fDnv.png)

Comment: How are you calling the callableFN?

Comment: What exactly do you see in the functions log in the Firebase console?

Comment: Is it normal that you assign the `onCreate` background triggered cloud Function to `const callableFN` or it is a typo in your question?

Comment: @JayCodist I'm calling in from an Angular component (sorry for the formatting)
`const newgame = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('callableFN');
        newgame({payloadData: SOMEDATA}})
           .then((resp) => {
             resp.data.state === 'ok' ? this.router.navigate(['account']) : window.alert('Something went wrong. We could not create the game. Please try again');
        });`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec you are correct. There was a small copy/pasted error in the code I posted. I have edited that piece.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the post to provide a screen cap of the logs. As an aside, anyone who can explain how to get the log details on a single line would have my gratitude!

Comment: Make sure that the service account has the required role (the App Engine default service account requires the `Editor` role).

Comment: Lee: Did the last comment help you?

Comment: @MrTech It did not. I ended up creating another db

Comment: Lee: Please let us know if you still have that original issue.

Comment: @MrTech As far as I know the problem still exists. I had to switch Firebase projects in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: Lee: You may choose to submit a bug report if you wish (https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).