# @google-cloud/firestore returns "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, permissions, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to use Google Cloud Functions to interact with a Google Firestore collection.  Going through the documentation, it seems like the suggested library to use is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore

the documentation on the library indicates it should only be used in a secure environment (like Cloud Functions) and that it would take advantage of ADC ( Application Default Credentials ).  However when I implement it in a cloud function I'm getting the following response from the library call to firestore.get()

```
{
    "code": 7,
    "details": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "metadata": {}
}
```

For the sake of this article lets say the project id is "mobile-site"

I made a firestore collection:

```
"site"
```

which has a single document:

```
{
  "hi": "there"
}
```

and a cloud function to call which attempts to get the document:

```
const firestore_1 = require("@google-cloud/firestore");

const projectId = 'mobile-site';
const firestore = new firestore_1.Firestore({ projectId });


/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  return TestStuff().then(v => {
    return res.status(200).send(v);
  }).catch(reason => {
    return res.status(500).send(reason)
  })
};

//
function TestStuff() {
  const collection = firestore.collection('site');
  return collection.get().then(query => {
    // this code is never invoked
    return {query, version: '1.0.1'}
  });
}
```

As a troubleshooting step, I did the exact same thing above on a personal account, and everything works swimmingly.  So its just my company's enterprise solution that causes an issue.

Before you say "check the Firestore Security Rules", this sdk circumvents the firestore rules since its in network and attached to a service account.  Speaking of which, here is the service account role/permissions, I've added quite a few in an effort to resolve the issue, so some may be completely unrelated, will use an example name:

IAM & Admin

example-service-account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

```
Editor
Service Account User
Viewer
```

Cloud Functions

example-service-account@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

```
Cloud Functions Admin
Cloud Functions Invoker
Cloud Functions Service Agent
Editor
Firebase Admin
```

Any help or suggestions to resolve or troubleshoot further are appreciated.

Comment: Weirdly strange shot in the dark... try adding Cloud Datastore User role to the Cloud Function's service account. I don't have much insight, but just to eliminate that as a thing it might be. If it is, I'll add more context.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Gabe and Marc.  Marc's link was very close to the solution I landed on (will post detail in a follow up comment)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue is there are multiple IAM "principal" role assignment areas.

Previously I had verified the service account settings here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/
Menu > IAM & ADMIN > Service Accounts > ( Clicking on the default service account ) > Permissions

However the location that resolved the issue for me was found here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/
Menu > IAM & ADMIN > IAM

In my case the service account in question wasn't even present, so it had to be added.  My administrators attached the following roles:

```
Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent
Service Account Token Creator
```

And now the functions work

User "Marc Anthony B" pointed me to

[Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore Trigger produces: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850494/firebase-cloud-functions-firestore-trigger-produces-error-7-permission-denied)

which was extremely close but not exactly the same since I am using a different library and the Role assignment is different.